# Converter decimal para binário - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá pessoal sou novo em python meu código abaixo exibe os valores da tabela ASCII para uma string digitada. Como posso pegar estes valores e converter para binário

```
valor = input("Insira o valor a ser criptografado: ")
print(valor) 
list=[ord(ch) for ch in valor]
print("Valores da tabela ASCII para:", valor, "são:", list, ".")
```

resultado (VALOR DIGITADO = teste):
Valores da tabela ASCII para (VALOR DIGITADO) são: [84, 69, 83, 84, 69] .

Agora preciso pegar 84 >> passar para binário e assim sucessivamente

por que posteriormente vou fazer uma função com uma chave e criptografar os valores etc.

Comment: Não é só fazer `bin(84)`?

Comment: Não sei te responder amigo , por isso perguntei, mas pesquisando sua dica..funcionou muito bem. Obrigado!

Comment: @Woss coloque sua sugestão como resposta para que ele possa escolher como resposta correta e fechar a pergunta. Ou então LeoMouraIOT coloque o que fez para resolver e marque como resposta correta para fechar a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sei que a resposta anterior já responde **suficientemente** a questão. Porém, resolvi a questão com uma nova roupagem. O código é:

```
valor = input('Insira um valor a ser criptografado: ')
for c in valor:
    v = ord(c)
    print(c, v, f'{v:b}', sep='\t')
```

Observe que neste código não utilizei a função **bin()**. Neste código utilizei **f-string** formatando para binário. Desta forma, podemos controlar a exibição do prefixo **"0b"**.

A parte do código que de fato converte um valor para binário é:

```
f'{v:b}'
```

Utilizando esta notação o valor binário será exibido sem o prefixo **0b**.

Agora, se preferirmos exibir o prefixo **0b**, basta utilizar o carácter **"#"** imediatamente antes da letra **"b"**. Neste caso o código ficaria:

```
f'{v:#b}'
```

Se preferirmos que todos os valores binários se apresentem com **8** dígitos, podemos utilizar o seguinte formato:

```
f'{v:08b}'
```

Desta forma, todos os valores binários terão **8 dígitos**.

Comment: para exercitar as f-strings, pode aproveitar e colocar um exemplo de como garantir 8 dígitos binários  - se olhar no exemplo da minha resposta, as letras "ma" tem só 7 dígitos - pderiam estar com o 0 na frente pra todas terem a mesma largura.

Comment: @jsbueno, formatação de valores binários com `8 dígitos`, realizada com sucesso.

Answer (score 6):

A função "bin" dá a representação binaria de um número como uma string. Mse ssa representação como string é útil apenas para mostrar os "0" e "1" na tela, para serem vistos por pessoas. Internamente, os algoritmos que trabalham com as letras, sejam de criptografia, ou outros, tem que usar os números - um número não tem uma "base" ele é uma quantidade - a representação dele como texto vai acontecer naturalmente em decimal, e a representação do número para os algoritmos que manipulam números bit a bit já é em binário.

O que você precisa, sim, é converter seu texto para uma codificação em Bytes. Se você usar só o "ord", você tem o codepoint Unicode que representa seu caractere, mas esse número - o codepoint- não tem uma largura fixa, e aí a maioria dos algoritmos de criptgrafia não vai funcionar (você pode assumir cada codepoint como uma largura de 32 bit, o equivalente  a usar utf-32, mas vai gastar espaço).

Resumindo, se pretende trabalhar com o texto com uma sequência de números, o melhor é transformar em um objeto do tipo "bytes", usando uma codificação adequada (por exemplo, "utf-8", que cobre todos os caracteres conhecidos). Um objeto "bytes" se você acessa cada elemento, já te dá o número, e não um objeto bytes de comprimento "1":

```py
In [138]: for x in "maçã".encode("utf-8"):
     ...:     print(x, end=", ")
     ...: 
109, 97, 195, 167, 195, 163,
```

Já, voltando na pergunta original, se você quiser, para fins de visuaçização, ver a representação binária dos números, é só usar a função "bin":

```
In [140]: for x in "maçã".encode("utf-8"):
     ...:     print(x, bin(x), sep="\t")
     ...: 
109     0b1101101
97      0b1100001
195     0b11000011
167     0b10100111
195     0b11000011
163     0b10100011
```

Comment: esse negócio de codificação é IMPORTANTÌSSIMO de entender, independente de você querer trabalhar com criptografia, etc... recomendo ler com muita atenção esse artigo aqui: https://papacharliefox3.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/o-minimo-de-conhecimento-basico-que-todo-desenvolvedor-de-software-deveria-saber-sem-qualquer-sombra-de-duvida-sobre-unicode-e-character-sets-sem-desculpas-esfarrapadas/